# Write shorthand if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write the below nested if statements in shorthand?

```
var count = 0;
if (count < 1){
   count ++;
   if(val1 == val2){    
      //do A
   }else{
      //do B
}else{          
   //do C
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I know it should be `++count < 1 ? val1 == val2 : //do A : //do B `... But How do I write nested if

Comment: 3rd or 4th question in row for shorthand. I would recommend to write proper readable code, when deploying look to minify your JS file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even shorter approach, no need for IIFE:

```
count < 1 ? (count++, val1 == val2 ? A() : B()) : C();
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just telling this is also another way of achieving in the chat! `:)`

Comment: Could you tell what's `b` comparing to my question? ( `count++, b = val1 ` )

Comment: @Becky, some left over.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) Ternary Operator for this:

```
var count = 0;
a = (count < 1) ? (function () { count++; b = (val1 == val2) ? A() : B(); }()) : C();
```

It is better to use ternary operators with return functions.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks +10. What about `++count < 1 ? val1 == val2 ? //do A : //do B : //do C ` Is that incorrect? Could you please explain.

Comment: @Becky Please, can you kindly edit the comment and make it readable? `:)`

Comment: @Becky That confuses the JavaScript compiler. I have got this solution by a series of trial and error only.

Comment: If you are not using a `(` and `)`, compiler doesn't know how to parse it.

Comment: Do you still need more clarification on this?

Comment: Thanks again. So `A()` should be `A( //do A )` ?

Comment: @Becky No no. If there is only single expression, just put it. If there are multiple, use a closure.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to understand what you've done rather than taking the answer.

Comment: @Becky I did tell you this idea over the chat, also I was the first one to answer. Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ternary operator(?:)` for shorthand statement for if else statement.

```
var count =0;
var result=(count<1) ? count++:val1==val2 ? alert("do A"):(alert("b"),alert("c"));
```